# Display and order using two meta keys

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have a custom wordpress page using a query for a meta key if the product is on special for a specific store, however I need to order them on page by a different meta_key called wpcf-order-by.

The following query does not work, it displays my items but not according to the wpcf-order-by.

what am I doing wrong, I have searched and I cannot find anything that suits my case

```
  $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'product',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'meta_key' => 'store_opening',
              'meta_value' => 'yes',
              'orderby' => 'wpcf-order-by',
              'order' => 'asc',
              'posts_per_page' => '-1'
          );
```

Comment: First of all can you please let us know in whether you are using a framework or Core PHP for this. If you are using a framework then can you mention which framework ? You can't just post a question with incomplete details. We can't go through each framework ever existed till now to check where you are facing an error.

Comment: @KishenNagaraju he is using wordpress, guess from the tags

Comment: Apologies, I though the tag was sufficient

Comment: @Ash-b - This forum is for helping others and not for guessing the php code.

Comment: @anthonytherockjohnson - No Problem. Please take care next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use meta_query for that.
meta_query fits to cases where you are working with more than one meta keys in your wp query requests.

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'product',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'meta_key' => 'wpcf-order-by',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value',
              'meta_query' => array(array(
                'key'     => 'store_opening',
                'value'   => 'yes',
                 )),
              'order' => 'asc',
              'posts_per_page' => '-1'
          );
```

If the values of 'wpcf-order-by' are numbers, then set 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' instead of 'meta_value'.